# Does Column Index changes upon adding a column manually in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form with 3 user input. They are called Voltage, Current, Temperature. Upon submitting the form, the spreadsheet will automatically capture the responses.

In a usual scenario, **Column A** will be the **Timestamp**, **Column B** will be **Voltage**, **Column C** will **Current** and **Column D** will be **Temperature**.

However, I tried to add a BLANK column for a separation after the Timestamp. So technically, Column B will be C and Column D will E and so on.

This is my original code

```java
var voltage = e.values[1]; //Represents Voltage
var current = e.values[2]; //Represents Current
var temperature = e.values[3]; //Represents Temperature
```

Will the indexes of the column change upon adding a blank column or will it remain as it is?

Comment: @Cooper - I just tested it myself. I added a left blank column. However, my indexes didn't change. As I mentioned, I have variable ``voltage`` from index 1. Currently my blank column is taking up Column B which is index 1. I tested with a code to send an email to myself. It still capture the proper voltage results. So I am confused right now, on how to to differentiate which column is the original and which is added and if it really makes an impact.

Comment: I was wrong they don't seem to change in the event object even though the positions of the columns change.  I just checked it with `function onFormSubmission(e) {
  Logger.log(e.values);
}`

Comment: Does it only change if its being added into the form itself or whatever that is being added after the initial creation of form will only just fill in the next right column? @Cooper

Comment: @D3FTY The indexes of the event object don't change when you add extra columns though they will auto populate into their new respective columns. What is it you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that, it does not change as I have 2 spreadsheets - one test and one live which is a google form. I have to get values from certain column and then assign it to a variable. That variable will then be used in an email function. However, I'm working on an old google form which has thousands of data in it. So I wanted to know how do I check if that specific column is actually added manually instead of being part of the google form which apparently has the same name as one of the question @RafaGuillermo

Comment: @D3FTY Is the form that was linked to the original old sheet still linked? You could create a new form response either in the UI or programmatically to check which columns are updates? Alternatively if it's no longer linked have you looked at the [revision history functionality of the Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions)? You would be able to see which columns were manually added via the revision history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.values` indexes aren't linked to sheet columns so if you insert a column the `e.values` indexes will not be changed, by the other hand, the position of values on `e.range.getValues()` will change.

Comment: Got it noted on that.